# SQL result group by 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which gives me the below result

```
FILE    EVENT   AMOUNT
File1   AP      26.96
File1   AP      26.96
File1   AP      26.96
```

Any idea on how to group result by 2 so that I can have

```
FILE    EVENT   AMOUNT
File1   AP      26.96
File1   AP      26.96
```

If my original query returns 4 results,

```
FILE    EVENT   AMOUNT
File1   AP      26.96
File1   AP      26.96
File1   AP      26.96
File1   AP      26.96
```

I would like to have

```
FILE    EVENT   AMOUNT
File1   AP      26.96
File1   AP      26.96
```

Any SQL keyword that does the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return 2 rows, then I'd look at using a windowing function like [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).  You can partition the data over the 3 columns and then filter it to only return 2 rows:

```
select [file], [event], [amount]
from
(
  select [file], [event], [amount],
    rn = row_number() over(partition by [file], [event], [amount]
                           order by [file])
  from dbo.yourtable
) d
where rn <= 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de955/2)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
;WITH    cteFiles
          AS ( SELECT   [FILE]
                       ,[EVENT]
                       ,[AMOUNT]
                       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [FILE], [EVENT], [AMOUNT] 
                                                 ORDER BY [FILE] ) AS rownum
               FROM     files
             )
    SELECT  [FILE]
           ,[EVENT]
           ,[AMOUNT]
    FROM    cteFiles
    WHERE   rownum <= 2;
```

see [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ac419/3)

Comment: Don't use single quotes to alias columns and tables. It's under deprecation and the names can be confused with string literals. And you are missing a `;` at the end of your query.

Comment: @ypercube, thanks for the heads-up.  I didn't use single quotes in the past, but after watching a pluralsight video, the author was suggesting it was good practice - I'll dig out the video.  I've changes the answer and fiddle.

Comment: @ypercube, it was Christopher Harrison on SQL Server 2012 Querying.  Maybe the decision to deprecate came after the video.

Comment: No, it's under deprecation since version 2008 but only the `'string_alias' = expression` syntax. Not the `expression AS 'string_alias'` (I thought they were both.) Anyway, I find it very confusing. Check also this blog by Aaron Bertrand: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Comment: yeah, it seems to be a preference thing, thanks for the link.

Answer (score -4):

Dude,
Group by groups the rows based on similar values in defined column.
In your example all your column values are same so group by will return 1 row.

If you want two rows you can try rownum also like

select x,y,z where rownum<=2;

Answer (score -4):

You just need two records or you need all records but two at a time?

If you just need two records then "Top" will help.

and if you need two records at a time then use following:-

```
WITH AllRecords AS (
Select Row_Number() Over(order by File) as RowID,File,Event,Amount from table
)
Select 
File,Event,Amount
from AllRecords 
where RowID>=@startIndex and RowID<=@endIndex
```

for Example:-
@startIndex could be 1,3,5...
@endIndex could be 2,4,6....
This can be calculated as :-

```
@startIndex=(pageNumber-1)*pageSize+1
@endIndex=pageNumber*pageSize
```

in your case page size will be 2.

Comment: You are bringing in unwanted complexity after other simple answers are already available.

Comment: Why pageSize concept and all coming here?